# calling function inside javascript class : this.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

> i've already seen this
>
> [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484)
>
> it doesn't mention classes , at least this syntax im using

im new to nodejs and js class so bear with me , im writing a  app with mvc like architecture

i got two methods in my controller , `wallet` and `generateWallet`

user will call `wallet` method via http request, it will check the database for wallet and if not exists it will call another function `generateWallet` which is supposed to be a private function to generate a new wallet and thats when i get the error

here i my code

```
class DashboardController {

  async wallet(req, res) {

    let wallet = await UserWalletRepository.find({
      user_id: req.authUser.id,
    });

    if (wallet) return res.send(wallet);

    let newWallet = await this.generateWallet(); 

    res.send(newWallet);
  }

  async generateWallet() {

    let generatedWallet = await WalletService.generateWallet();
    let newWallet = await UserWalletRepository.create({
      user_id: req.authUser.id,
      ...generatedWallet,
    });

    return newWallet;
  }
}

module.exports = new DashboardController();
```

here is the error

```
TypeError: this.generateWallet is not a function
at wallet (C:\node\first\app\controller\api\dashboard-controller.js:16:32)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

specifically this like

```
let newWallet = await this.generateWallet();
```

i assume something is changing `this` keyword but i cant figure out what , there are routers and other codes involved in the stack but i dont think they have any effect since we are inside the function when we get this error ?

here is how i've set up my filder/files

so i have `router` folder with `api` and `web` folder inside ,  containing route files for each section for example in `routes/api/dashboard.js` i have

```
const DashboardController = require("../../app/controller/api/dashboard-controller");
const { AuthMiddleware } = require("../../app/middleware/auth");
module.exports = {
  group: {
    prefix: "/dashboard",
    middleware: [AuthMiddleware],
  },
  routes: [
    {
      method: "get",
      path: "/",
      handler: DashboardController.index,
    },
    {
      method: "get",
      path: "/wallet",
      handler: DashboardController.wallet,
    },
  ],
};
```

and i have `routes/inedx.js` which grabs all the route files and adds them to express

```
const express = require("express");
require("express-async-errors");
const webRoutes = require("./web/index");
const apiRoutes = require("./api/index");
class Router {
  constructor() {
    this.router = express.Router();
  }

  create(app) {
    this._attachMiddleware();
    this._attachWebRoutes();
    this._attachApiRoutes();
    app.use(this.router);
  }

  _attachMiddleware() {
    this.router.use(express.json());
  }


  _attachWebRoutes() {
    this._attachRoutes(webRoutes);
  }
  _attachApiRoutes() {
    this._attachRoutes(apiRoutes, "/api");
  }

  _attachRoutes(routeGroups, globalPrefix = "") {
    routeGroups.forEach(({ group, routes }) => {
      routes.forEach(({ method, path, middleware = [], handler }) => {
        this.router[method](
          globalPrefix + group.prefix + path,
          [...(group.middleware || []), ...middleware],
          handler
        );
      });
    });
  }


}

module.exports = new Router();
```

i have `server/index.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const Router = require('../router/index')

class Server {

    constructor(port){
        this.port = port ; 
        this.app = express();
    }


    start(){
        this._setupRoutes();
        this._listin();
    }

    _listin(){
        this.app.listen(this.port , ()=>{
            console.log('app running on port' , this.port);
        })
    }

    _setupRoutes(){
        
        Router.create(this.app)

    }
}

module.exports = Server ;
```

and finally my `index.js`

```
const Server = require('./server/index');
const app = new Server(8080);
app.start();
```

Comment: `require('./server/inedx');` - typo.

Comment: `handler: DashboardController.wallet` - this is **not** bound. This is absolutely covered by the canonical dupe. _(Also more broadly there is no point using classes for controllers, they don't have any state.)_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but try changing `require('./server/inedx')` in your index.js to `require('./server/index')` and your mentions of `req.authUsre.id` to `req.authUser.id`

Comment: @neopythe sorry i corrected the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem you are having is related to how you assign the `DashboardController.wallet` to the handler which makes `this` to be unbound:

```
{
  method: "get",
  path: "/wallet",
  handler: DashboardController.wallet,
}
```

Since you don't have class variables, you can make your methods static and not use `this` at all:

```
class DashboardController {
  static async wallet(req, res) {
    let wallet = await UserWalletRepository.find({
      user_id: req.authUser.id,
    });

    if (wallet) return res.send(wallet);

    let newWallet = await DashboardController.generateWallet();

    res.send(newWallet);
  }

  static async generateWallet() {
    let generatedWallet = await WalletService.generateWallet();
    let newWallet = await UserWalletRepository.create({
      user_id: req.authUser.id,
      ...generatedWallet,
    });

    return newWallet;
  }
}
module.exports = DashboardController;
```

alternatively, you can use `.bind()` to set the `this` explicitly:

```
{
  method: "get",
  path: "/wallet",
  handler: DashboardController.wallet.bind(DashboardController),
}
```